# How to run apple script after completion of previous one

Tags: applescript

I am to running some terminal commands using apple script. 
The problem i am facing is that i want to run 2nd command only after the 1st one finishes. 
I can not add delay statement bcoz the finishing time of command 1 is not fix, it changes as per the size of file for which  i am running that command. 
How to do that? Can any body help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do shell script "command 1; command 2"
```

Comment: Hi i tried this using 
do shell script "ls ; sudo"
 but it is showing some error as follows

AppleScript Error
usage: sudo -K | -L | -V | -h | -k | -l | -v

can u please explain in detail, how to do as per answer?

Comment: sudo isn't usually used on its own, it's a way of running a process with super-user priveleges, without logging in as a super user. So you might use "sudo rm /some/file.foo" to remove a file that you need root priveleges to remove. To use sudo you will have to supply the admin password, which you can do in applescript with: do shell script "sudo rm /some/file.foo" with administrator privileges password "mypassword". Sudo has a homepage (like any *nix app): http://www.sudo.ws/